# Setting up Devise on existing Rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, heroku, devise

I'm working with an existing Rails app, and I come across a 500 error page at the point where a confirmation email is supposed to be sent to the user. The views and controllers have already been created for the mailout, but I'm wondering if I need to set up Devise on my machine since I forked the files from an existing repo.

Feel free to take a look at the code below:

```
  #customer_controller.rb

  def create
   @customer = Customer.new(customer_params)
   begin
    CheckoutMailer.welcome_customer(@customer).deliver
   end
   render :confirm;
  end


#checkout_mailer.rb
  def welcome_customer customer
   @customer = customer
   mail(:to => "EMAIL ADDRESS",
        :subject => "Welcome!"
   )
  end

#production.rb
  config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { host: 'URL to Heroku app' }
  config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
  config.action_mailer.default :charset => "utf-8"
  config.action_mailer.perform_deliveries = true
  config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = true
  config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
   address: "smtp.gmail.com",
   port: 587,
   domain: "URL",
   authentication: "plain",
   enable_starttls_auto: true,
   user_name: "GMAIL ACCOUNT NAME",
   password: "PASSWORD"
  }
```

The confirm page renders when I remove `mail(:to => "EMAIL ADDRESS", :subject => "Welcome!")` from checkout_mailer.rb.

Comment: What does the stack trace say? Posting the stack trace with your questions will help people help you :). It also might be that you set `config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = true` and you are not using valid gmail account login credentials or you are trying to send an email to an invalid email address.

Comment: Agreed with @FaithoftheFallen - what does your logging output? Seeing the actual answer would definitely help us reach a solution, otherwise we are just shooting in the dark.